# Adding top n column based on another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Example dataframe:

```
   Item_Name   Price 
   Basket        2       
   Carpet        5       
   Basket        3      
   Carpet        10       
   Rug           2      
   Rug           3      
   foo           1
```

I want to add a column called top 3 which indicates whether or not the item is top 3 based on total price summed for each item. The total price or basket is 5, carpet is 15, rug is 5 and foo is 1. So, everything except foo falls in the top 3. How do I do this? I need a new column named "top" 3 that indicates yes or no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `sum` to find the sum of each `Item_Name`, then create a list of the 3 largest index values using the `nlargest` function as suggested by @Henry Yik.

```
top3 = df.groupby("Item_Name")["Price"].sum().nlargest(3).index
```

Then use `.isin` to check if each Item_name is in the top3 list we created

```
df["top3"] = df["Item_Name"].isin(top3)
```

Result:

```
>>> df
  Item_Name  Price   top3
0    Basket      2   True
1    Carpet      5   True
2    Basket      3   True
3    Carpet     10   True
4       Rug      2   True
5       Rug      3   True
6       foo      1  False
```

Comment: You can use [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html), i.e. `df.groupby("Item_Name")["Price"].sum().nlargest(3)`. Didn't downvote you though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'll update my answer! I wasn't aware that this function existed but I can see why pandas would have a more performant function for what I wrote

Answer (score 1):

Given your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Item_Name': ['Basket', 'Carpet', 'Basket', 'Carpet', 'Rug', 'Rug', 'foo'],
                   'Price': [2, 5, 3, 10, 2, 3, 1]})
```

First you can aggregate the prices based on the item name to get the sums of the prices.

```
agg_df = df.groupby('Item_Name').sum()
print(agg_df)
```

Output:

```
           Price
Item_Name       
Basket         5
Carpet        15
Rug            5
foo            1
```

Then you can use `nlargest` to get the top 3 items by price.

```
top_3_df = agg_df.nlargest(3, 'Price')
print(top_3_df)
```

Output:

```
           Price
Item_Name       
Carpet        15
Basket         5
Rug            5
```

Then you need to get a list of the top 3 values from the index of that dataframe:

```
top_3 = list(top_3_df.index.values)
print(top_3)
```

Output:

```
['Carpet', 'Basket', 'Rug']
```

Finally, you can add a new column indicating which item names are in the top 3 list.

```
df["top3"] = df["Item_Name"].isin(top_3)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Item_Name  Price   top3
0    Basket      2   True
1    Carpet      5   True
2    Basket      3   True
3    Carpet     10   True
4       Rug      2   True
5       Rug      3   True
6       foo      1  False
```